# Пауза в бесконечном цикле по кнопке

Tags: c++

Консольное приложение.
Есть цикл, в нем по очереди вызываются 3 метода класса. Нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку с клавиатуры (к примеру 'A') цикл останавливался, с возможностью продолжения по кнопке (к примеру 'S').

Comment: 'Есть цикл' - если он есть хорошо бы его добавить в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, как-то так:

```
char c;
while(1)
{
    ...
        if(kbhit()) // если была нажата какая-нибудь клавиша
        {
            if((c=getch())=='A') // если это буква 'A'
            {
                while(getch()!='S'); // то висеть на ф-ии приёма символа, пока он не будет равен 'S'
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно

Comment: @nueq Никак не пойму, чем этот ответ отличается от ответа Harry?

Comment: @Mikhailo вообще никак не отличается.  просто пока я долго писал свой ответ, Harry успел написать свой.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то типа

```
for(...)
{
    ....... // Бурная деятельность

    if (kbhit())
    {
        char c = getch();
        if (c == 'A')
        {
            while(getch() != 'S');
        }
    }
}
```

не устроит?... Или я неверно понял вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

Выглядеть это могло бы как-то так:

```
volatile bool pauseCondition = false;

while (true) {

    while (pauseCondition) sleep(100);

    doPayloadIteration();
}
```

Тем временем на `pauseCondition` может воздействовать другой поток, который обрабатывает пользовательсткий ввод.